# No Documentation Available error in Spyder

Tags: pandas, spyder

In Spyder IDE, I can't able to get the help option when I press Ctrl+I . It shows 'No Documentation Available'. I have even checked the preferences option but still not working.How to rectify this ?

Comment: same problem , please tell a solution if found.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not possible to show docs for every package due to technical limitations. But if this failing for all of them, I think it is a bug which should be fixed in our 5.0.2 version, to be released shortly.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba For your information, this bug still happens. I've got `5.0.5`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Spyder 4.1.5. It's solved by downloading and installing Kite. Make sure the Spyder Kite plugin configuration is in line with this guide: https://help.kite.com/article/90-using-the-spyder-plugin